# How can I split a list into two that can hold odd number of counts?

Tags: c#, sql, list

I have a sql list "GetStaff()" that has 9 people in it and when the code runs it splits them in two teams but only displays 4 in each team. I cannot get the 9th member to be displayed in the team.How can I adjust the code to hold odd number of people and not just even in a split team.Any help would be helpful.

```
public List<Staff[]> CreateTeams(int membersPerTeam)
        {
            IList<Staff> allUsers = GetStaff();
            int teamCount = allUsers.Count / membersPerTeam;
            int usersPerTeam = allUsers.Count / 2;
            var teams = new List<Staff[]>();

            for (int i = 0; i < teamCount; i++)
            {
                Staff[] team = new Staff[membersPerTeam];
                for (int j = 0; j < usersPerTeam ; j++)
                {
                    team[j] = allUsers[i * membersPerTeam + j];
                }
                teams.Add(team);
            }
            return teams;
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter which team, it just needs to be in a team

Comment: Looking at it again, I think I found a logical error. `membersPerTeam` is given as parameter. Why compute `usersPerTeam`, restricting the number of teams to 2? I think you need to review the actual requirements of this function.

Comment: I need the teams to be 2 thats y I have divided it in 2 and no more.

Comment: Then your requirement doesn't fit well with your argument. You don't need it at all. It obviously just confuses you, and prospective clients of that function, too.

Comment: Ok, I need a clarification here: Why do you have `membersPerTeam` in the first place? You know, you want 2 Teams. You **do not know** how many prospective team members there are in total. So how is the client expected to know what to input? The number of team members depends solely on the total member count. Whatever you pass, it will only ever be correct if it is exactly == totalCount/2 ... so you can either ignore it, or leave some members potentially "unplaced".

Comment: I might have done mistakes in the code and that is because I am new to C# its beneficial for me you helping out. It will help me not to make this mistakes again.

Comment: @Fildor I understand what you are trying to say, I have made mistakes thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: You are welcome. I hope I could help you see them. You can only learn by making mistakes :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Enigmativity's answer and clarifications in comments, I'd suggest a simplyfied version of his solution:

```
public List<Staff[]> CreateTwoTeams() // No argument => You don't know the total number
{
    return
        GetStaff()                             // Get all members
            .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })    // add an index
            .GroupBy(z => z.n % 2)             // Create 2 Groups: Even and Odd
            .Select(zs => zs.Select(z => z.x)  // For each Group: make an array 
                             .ToArray())       // of the members
            .ToList();                         // Make a List of those arrays.
}
```

If you later chose to make the *number of teams* variable, you can simply introduce an argument and replace the hardcoded "2" by it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use LINQ:

```
public List<Staff[]> CreateTeams(int membersPerTeam)
{
    IList<Staff> allUsers = GetStaff();
    int teams = allUsers.Count() / membersPerTeam + allUsers.Count() % membersPerTeam == 0 ? 0 : 1;;
    return
        allUsers
            .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
            .GroupBy(z => z.n % teams)
            .Select(zs => zs.Select(z => z.x).ToArray())
            .ToList();
}
```

This simply projects the list to include an `n` index number and then groups by the modulus of `membersPerTeam` against that `n`. Then it removes the index and returns the results.

Comment: If not automatically added, you need to add a `using System.Linq` to the using section. Then you can write the Linq extension methods as shown in the answer.  Here, Linq is also mixed with [expression-bodied Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods) which is a separate concept to Linq.

Comment: @Milbon7: Mind that this solution my contain an array that is shorter than `membersPerTeam`.

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity. It creates 4 teams would u be able to help as to how I can just make it 2 teams?

Comment: The name `membersPerTeam` is confusing here, since it is actually `numberOfTeams`. So if you set it to 2 it should do what you want. @Milbon7

Comment: @Enigmativity Am I right here? `memebersPerTeam` actually determines the number of teams, not the number of members in each team.

Comment: @Enigmativity I really don't want to be nitpicky. This is a great solution. It's just ... `teams` may resolve to be 0, right? And then OP wants exactly 2 Teams, which imho leaves the argument `memebersPerTeam` somewhat useless, even counter-productive.

Comment: @Fildor - It should really be the number of `teams` as the parameter.

Comment: @Fildor - Now, that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This line is likely to be your problem

```
 int usersPerTeam = allUsers.Count / 2;
```

When you have an odd number this will lose the decimal part, 9 / 2 = 4 when the result must be an `int`

Try checking for the odd number, and adding one if it is odd

```
var userCount = allUsers.Count % 2 = 0 ? allUsers.Count : allUsers.Count + 1
int teamCount = userCount / 2
```